# how to extract values from multiple functions into one in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am working with a code that has multiple functions writing new variables. I am trying to save those values from all different functions into another one.

Example:

```
function LoadNews(obj)
    args.sir = obj.sir;
    args.date = obj.date;
    args.news = news;
    BSQL.save_star_stats(args);    

function LoadMoons(obj)   
    args.moon = moon;
    args.comet = comet;
    BSQL.save_star_stats(args); 

function LoadLight(obj)   
     args.light = light;
     args.speed = speed;
     BSQL.save_star_stats(args);
```

After I ran this, I get the following error:

```
Reference to non-existent field 'comet'.
```

Is there an easy way to grab values from multiple functions and save them into one?

Comment: There needs to be more context to this code.  Specifically, the variables like `news`, `moon`, `comet`, `light` and `speed` are undefined in this context.    Also, `args` seems to be referenced yet there is no declaration... same with `BSQL`.  Are these `global` variables?  As is, this code will not run.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting what you want done, you wish to mutate `args` at each function call.  Specifically, you want `args` to remember all of the fields you are assigning to it at each function call.  That can very easily be done by setting the output of each function to `args`, as well as providing it as an input.  Simply put:

```
function args = LoadNews(args, obj)
    args.sir = obj.sir;
    args.date = obj.date;
    args.news = news;
    BSQL.save_star_stats(args);    

function args = LoadMoons(args, obj)   
    args.moon = moon;
    args.comet = comet;
    BSQL.save_star_stats(args); 

function args = LoadLight(args, obj)   
     args.light = light;
     args.speed = speed;
     BSQL.save_star_stats(args);
```

Once this is done, you can try calling the code like so:

```
args = LoadNews(args, obj);
args = LoadMoons(args, obj);
args = LoadLight(args, obj);
```

This is my best guess given the current state of your code and its context.  Once you complete the above code, `args` should remember everything you've done to it when you run all of the functions.